# setting up pythonnet to run against a virtual environment on a 64 bit raspberrypi

Tags: raspberry-pi, 64-bit, python-venv, .net-7.0, python.net

After upgrading to a 64 bit os on a raspberry pi i cant install the python modules i need globally using pip so have been trying ot use a virtual environment but cant get it to work in .net7 with pythonnet. It does work against the global environment though.

```
var environmentPythonDLLPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PYTHONNET_PYDLL") ?? @"/usr/lib/python3.11/config-3.11-aarch64-linux-gnu/libpython3.11.so"; ;
        //environmentPythonDLLPath = "/home/paul/Dotnet.Bledom.Api/PythonEnv/bin/python3";
        Runtime.PythonDLL = environmentPythonDLLPath;
        /*
         * 
         * <PropertyGroup>
                <EnableUnsafeBinaryFormatterSerialization>true</EnableUnsafeBinaryFormatterSerialization>
            </PropertyGroup>

        However, these are only temporary workarounds and you should migrate to a safer serialization method as soon as possible. For example, you can use JsonSerializer or XmlSerializer to serialize and deserialize C# objects to and from JSON or XML formats2. You can also use the ToPython and AsManagedObject methods from the Python.Runtime library to convert C# objects to Python objects and vice versa3.
         */
        AppContext.SetSwitch("System.Runtime.Serialization.EnableUnsafeBinaryFormatterSerialization", true);



        var pythonVirtualPath = Path.Combine(_env.ContentRootPath, "PythonEnv");

        // Set the Python DLL path, Python home, and Python path environment variables
        // You may need to adjust these paths according to your Python installation and virtual environment location
        string pythonDllPath = environmentPythonDLLPath; 
        string pythonHome = pythonVirtualPath; 
   
        var pythonPath = @"/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/thonny/plugins/cpython_backend;/usr/lib/python311.zip;/usr/lib/python3.11;/usr/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload;/home/paul/Dotnet.Bledom.Api/PythonEnv/lib/python3.11/site-packages;"+ @"/home/paul/PythonEnv/Dev/lib/python3.11/site-packages;/home/paul/PythonEnv/Dev/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages;/home/paul/PythonEnv/Dev/lib/python3/dist-packages;/home/paul/PythonEnv/Dev/lib/python3.11/dist-packages";

        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", pythonDllPath, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PYTHONHOME", pythonHome, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PYTHONPATH", pythonPath, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);                  
        
        PythonEngine.PythonHome = pythonVirtualPath;
        PythonEngine.PythonPath = pythonPath;
        //PythonEngine.PythonPath = PythonEngine.PythonPath + ";" + Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PYTHONPATH", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
        

        PythonEngine.Initialize();
```

On calling initialize i get the following error:

```
    Loaded '__Python_Runtime_Generated_Assembly0'. 
  Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = '/home/paul/Dotnet.Bledom.Api/PythonEnv'
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = 'python3'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  safe_path = 0
  import site = 1
  is in build tree = 0
  stdlib dir = ''
  sys._base_executable = '/usr/bin/python3'
  sys.base_prefix = ''
  sys.base_exec_prefix = ''
  sys.platlibdir = 'lib'
  sys.executable = '/usr/bin/python3'
  sys.prefix = ''
  sys.exec_prefix = ''
  sys.path = [
    '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/thonny/plugins/cpython_backend;/usr/lib/python311.zip;/usr/lib/python3.11;/usr/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload;/home/paul/Dotnet.Bledom.Api/PythonEnv/lib/python3.11/site-packages;/home/paul/PythonEnv/Dev/lib/python3.11/site-packages;/home/paul/PythonEnv/Dev/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages;/home/paul/PythonEnv/Dev/lib/python3/dist-packages;/home/paul/PythonEnv/Dev/lib/python3.11/dist-packages',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'
```

Current thread 0x0000007faecd0040 (most recent call first):

How can i resolve this to setup the virtual environment properly in pythonnet, or is there a workaround to get the pip modules in my global python? the virtual environment works in a terimnal or thonny and i got my path lib with

```
import sys print(";".join(sys.path))
```

Can I just copy the pip installed modules from my virtual env lib to the global lib in usr as a workaround?

I am using

```
 <PackageReference Include="pythonnet" Version="3.0.3" />
```

and the python 3.11 that came pre installed on the latest release of 64 bit debian from the raspberry pi website